# Angular: error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable ... with share() operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, observer-pattern

I'm new to Angular 5 and I'm implementing the Observable/Observer pattern in order to share some events and some data changes to the subcribers.

Here the snippet of code:

```
...
@Injectable()
export class NidoService {
  ...
  event$: Observable<StrutturaDto[]>;
  private _observer: Observer<any>;

  event_dettaglio$: Observable<Struttura>;
  private _observer_dettaglio: Observer<any>;

  constructor() {
     this.event$ = new Observable(observer => this._observer = observer).share();
     this.event_dettaglio$ = new Observable(observer => this._observer_dettaglio = observer).share();
  }
  ...
}
```

When I try to build the application with **ng build** I get these errors on the two lines of code within the **constructor**:

```
ERROR in src/app/services/nido.service.ts(28,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<StrutturaDto[]>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'StrutturaDto[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.
src/app/services/nido.service.ts(29,7): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Struttura>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Struttura'.
Property 'idStruttura' is missing in type '{}'.
```

When I use it in development mode I have no problems, but I cannot build without fixing them. How can I change the two lines of code?

Comment: Try replacing the first constructor line by this `this.event$ = new Observable(observer => {this._observer = observer; return undefined;}).share();`

Comment: In your example observer and observable have different types. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of observable:

```
this.event$ = new Observable<StrutturaDto[]>(observer => this._observer = observer).share();
```

and

```
this.event_dettaglio$ = new Observable<Struttura>(observer => this._observer_dettaglio = observer).share();
```